# How can I check theme exist or not in cakephp 3.x and set default theme if not exist

Tags: cakephp, themes, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to set theme dynamically in cakephp 3.x . So I have to check theme exist or not. If exist than I will set otherwise it will get default theme.

```
if($themeNameExist){
  $this->viewBuilder()->theme($themeName);
}
```

But i did not get any function or way how can I check theme exist or not? Anybody can you help?

Answer (score 2):

In CakePHP 3, themes are plugins, so you could use the functionality for testing whether a plugin is loaded, like

```
use Cake\Core\Plugin;

if (Plugin::loaded($themeName) === true) {
}
```

See also **[API > \Cake\Core\Plugin::loaded()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Core.Plugin.html#_loaded)**

Depending on why exactly you need to check/set themes dynamically, it might be wise to maintain a whitelist of allowed theme names, as allowing to arbitrary reference plugins (which don't necessarily have to be themes), may to some extent pose a security problem!

```
$allowedThemes = [
    'FooTheme', 'BarTheme', 'BazTheme'
];

if (
    in_array($themeName, $allowedThemes) &&
    Plugin::loaded($themeName) === true
) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Basically I need to check theme because of to set theme according to specific  action which controlled by RBAC. Such as administrative, registered and public etc

Answer (score 0):

I have find one solution such as where I have checked theme folder exist or not.

use Cake\Filesystem\Folder;

```
$themeName = 'ThemeName';
    $Folder = new Folder(ROOT);
    if ($Folder->inPath('plugins' . DS.$themeName)) {
        $this->viewBuilder()->theme($themeName);
    }
```